# Creating a bot but getting error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-bot-service

Thanks for all your replies and apologies if I miss out on anything in description.

I am trying to create an echo bot in the azure service, but when I click on "Create" it returns an error stating: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

It doesn't seem to be much what I could have done wrong, but I am sure there is something.

[image: Screenshot:]

Thanks once again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's intermittent issue, please follow create an azure bot service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0